# 100% Height Div Issue

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to make a full page DIV that holds all my content but expands when other divs are larger than the screen size and it wont auto expand you can view the website at http://molly.everythingcreative.co.uk (sorry the background images haven't been sized yet so files are quite large). I was currently using the Stickyfooter code to make the DIV stay full screen but it seems it causes a gap at the bottom of the page on either resize or expanding of DIVS:

```
#global_main_frame {
    width: 350px;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 50px 0px 50px;
    float: left;
    left: -600px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 200;
}
```

Example

```
<div id="global_main_frame">
<!-- All the other DIV's -->
</div>
```

Comment: The site looks ok to me in Chromium 21.0.1180.89 (or maybe I don't understand what the issue is).

Comment: If you click on Accommodation so it expands larger than the screen you will see about a 10px DIV. Or just resize your browser so it is smaller than the text and scroll down you will see it...it has been annoying the hell out of me!!

Comment: take a look at this http://molly.everythingcreative.co.uk/screen.png you can see the gap and ive tried it on safari/chrome/FireFox and they all do the same

Comment: Yeah I've since noticed it but I can't figure out why.. give me a couple minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `clearfix` class on the `#global_main_frame` element that is causing the gap. If you change the `visibility` style rule on the `clearfix` class to `visible` you can see the dot that is inserted below your full screen div to clear the float.

To remove the gap you can either add `font-size: 0` to `clearfix`, or remove the `clearfix` class from the `#global_main_frame` element (it's not needed when the container is the body element).

Comment: Just came to the same conclusion, +1

Comment: OMG!! This is the first time I've used clearfix i always use clear:both. You are a legend!